# Terminal Transparency in Ubuntu GNOME Malfunctions

Tags: gnome, gtk, ubuntu-gnome

I recently installed ubuntu GNOME and I have done all the updates and upgrades. When I try to add transparency to my terminal it don't work. It only goes dark-black to white.

**Transparency set to none**:

[image: Transparency set to none]

**Transparency set to maximum**

[image: Transparency set to maximum]

However, when I have added transparency to the terminal and I go into Help -> About, the terminal window applies the right transparency, (very strange).

**Transparency with about box open**

[image: Transparency with about box open]

I would really appreciate some assistance with this issue.

Comment: Your question reads like you are actually asking two unrelated questions. Is this question about gnome-terminal transparency not working, or is it about the error you get from compiz? Please edit your question to just one, or somehow explain how you think they are related.

Comment: It's about the transparency. I have edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: see your last screen shot it's already transparent-ed, and why in you first and second it's not take effect and goes to black/white, I have to say, because background wallpaper/window is white colored.

Comment: It is a bug in gnome-terminal. See here.https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1292282

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have now upgraded to GNOME Version 3.12.2 and to my surprise, there isn't a background tab anymore.

[image: No Background Tab## Heading ##]

**Reason:**
I did some research and found out that the background transparency feature has been removed due to complications. Read it below from *Allan Day* :

> I've spoken to Christian and he has filled me in on the background to
>   this issue.
>
> The ability to set background transparency was removed as
>   a part of a much larger clean up of the gnome-terminal code base. This
>   modernisation effort is much needed and it should be remembered that
>   the terminal has an old and complicated code base. Background
>   transparency was also known to cause a range of performance issues,
>   including slowness and memory leaks.
>
> Given the number of active terminal developers, the need to clean up the code base and known bugs
>   with background transparency, it was decided that the resources were
>   not available to maintain background transparency and keep the quality
>   to the required level.
>
> We understand that some users are disappointed
>   by the disappearance of this feature, and we hope that they understand
>   that this decision was made to enable other improvements to the
>   terminal code, and that it will lead to other improvements in the long
>   run. While Christian’s initial response could have been better, he has
>   responded in detail in private mail and I suspect that he was simply
>   tired of the issue.

Source: [Bug 698544](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=698544), Comment #45

**Solution:**
However, I have found a resolution to this issue by installing terminator `sudo apt-get install terminator`

[image: Transparency Again]

---

Done